# cannot change NEW values for this trigger type

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a trigger that would give discount to the customer with id 24535 when a new row is inserted in the table, and i get the error in the tittle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOP_DISCOUNT 
AFTER INSERT ON PURCHASE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF :old.ClientNo = 24535 THEN
    :new.Amount := :old.Amount * 0.85;
    END IF;
END;
```

this is what the table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE (
    PURCHASENO  NUMBER(5),
    RECEIPTNO   NUMBER(6),
    SERVICETYPE VARCHAR2(25),
    PAYMENTTYPE VARCHAR2(10),
    GST     VARCHAR2(3),
    AMOUNT      NUMBER(4),
    SERVEDBY    NUMBER(4),
    CLIENTNO    NUMBER(5)
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `before insert` instead of `after insert`

Comment: Also insert trigger do not have any :old values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`After insert` trigger can not change the value which is going to be inserted and also `:old` is not supported in `insert trigger`.

Your trigger should be like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOP_DISCOUNT 
BEFORE INSERT ON PURCHASE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF :new.ClientNo = 24535 THEN
        :new.Amount := :new.Amount * 0.85;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Cheers!!